# ImportError: cannot import name output

Tags: python, fabric

iam using fabric 0.9.1 version on windows to do some deployment related stuff.

But the moment iam about to run **"fab hello"**  iam facing the following error

```
D:\pythonscripts>fab hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\fab-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fabric==0.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_poi
nt
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_po
int
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\main.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\api.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\context_managers.py", line 12, in <modu
le>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\state.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\network.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fabric\utils.py", line 21, in abort
ImportError: cannot import name output
```

Any clue on how to resolve this error?

Comment: How does your hello script look like? And what other .py files do you have in pythonscripts directory?

Comment: 1) pythonscripts directory has only this file
2) script just has two lines like 
   def hello():
     print("Hello world!")

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be this issue: http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/194, probably it's not Fabric related but PyCrypto or Python64. If it is PyCrypto then the easiest thing is to download a binary version from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto and install it and download pywin32 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/ and install it as well.